# What is 'Started' status of a task?

Tags: task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a task started it with a Alter task task_name resume command but can see started status. does that mean it is scheduled i do not have permission to view task_history table.

Comment: Hi did you try SHOW task , you should be able to see "state" column , it will display ‘Started’ or ‘Suspended’ based on the current state of the task.

Answer (score 0):

RESUME brings a suspended task to a usable ‘Started’ state, which simply means the task runs on a schedule, which you defined when creating a task.